# Correct syntax for friend template function

Tags: c++, templates, friend

In The C++ Programming Language, Fourth Edition - chapter 23.4.7 Friends, I found following example (I have slightly modified it to show only relevant part):

```
template<typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    friend Vector operator*<>(const Vector& v, int f); 
                           ^^ ~~~~ ?
};

template<typename T>
Vector<T> operator*(const Vector<T>& v, int f) {
    return v;
}
```

I tried to compile it, but I get following error (clang):

```
main.cpp:8:20: error: friends can only be classes or functions
        friend Vector operator*<>(const Vector& v, int f); 
                      ^
main.cpp:8:29: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
        friend Vector operator*<>(const Vector& v, int f); 
                               ^
                               ;
2 errors generated.
```

Book explains that :

> The <> after the name of the friend function is needed to make clear that the friend is a template function. Without the <>, a non template function would be assumed.

And that is all on this.

Without `<>` this code compiles, but when operator* is used (ex.: `Vector<int> v; v*12;`) then linker error appears:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `operator*(Vector<int> const&, int)'
```

So I assume that `<>` is needed to tell compiler that function template for operator* should be generated each time Vector template is instantiated for given type.

But what am I doing wrong in the example from the book, and why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the book said,

> the `<>` after the name of the friend function is needed to make clear that the friend is a template function.

That means, the name should refer to a function template, which should be declared (as template) in advance. e.g.

```
// forward declaration of the class template
template<typename T>
class Vector;

// declaration of the function template
template<typename T>
Vector<T> operator*(const Vector<T>& v, int f);

template<typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    // friend declaration
    friend Vector operator*<>(const Vector& v, int f); 
};

// definition of the function template
template<typename T>
Vector<T> operator*(const Vector<T>& v, int f) {
    return v;
}
```

Comment: why we need forward declaration of class template ?

Comment: @Spartacus Because its name is used in the declaration of the function template.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, you're *declaring* `operator*` as a friend directly inside `Vector`, without any previous declaration. Therefore the correct syntax is:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    template<typename>
    friend Vector operator*(const Vector& v, int f);               
};

template<typename T>
Vector<T> operator*(const Vector<T>& v, int f) {
    return v;
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RPVkid4ZyBeQyhl4)

Comment: Is there any difference between those two methods? In songyuanyao answer, I learnt that I must declare template operator* before the class, from your answer I can declare it after the class. Is that the only difference in behaviour?

Comment: @mike For this case, two things are done at the same time; (1) declare the template function, (2) make it the friend. The behavior is the same as the non-template friend function declarations.

Comment: ok, so `<>` is only to let the compiler know that operator* was already declared and it is a template - right?

Comment: @mike Yes. More precisely, `<>` is only telling the compiler that this is a template. Because it's not a template declaration itself (as the case in romeo's answer), the compiler need to find the declaration of the template. That's why it has to be declared in advance; otherwise the compiler would complain.

Answer (score 2):

To make template friend method syntax work you need a forward declaration of this template method.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Vector;

template<typename T>
Vector<T> operator*(const Vector<T>& v, int f);

template<typename T>
class Vector
{
    template<typename T_> friend
    Vector<T_> operator*(const Vector<T_>& v, int f);
};

template<typename T>
Vector<T> operator*(const Vector<T>& v, int f)
{
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see this is the same as in Vittorio Romeo answer. But those declarations of class Vector and operato* are not needed. And also typename before Vector causes compile errors.

Comment: No, this is not exactly the same as Vittorio Romeo answer. In general case one can not get away with <> and need all these forward declarations. For example if you had another template method that is a bit more complex: template<typename T, int whatever>
Vector<T> operator*(const Vector<T>& v, int f);

Answer (score 0):

Whatever book you're using is explaining it incorrectly.

What you need to do is

```
template<typename T>
class Vector
{
       public:
           friend Vector<T> operator*(const Vector<T>& v, int f); 
};

template<typename T>
   Vector<T> operator*(const Vector<T>& v, int f)
{
    return v;
}
```

The above makes the `operator*()` which accepts a `Vector<T>` a friend of `Vector<T>` but not a friend of `Vector<U>` (unless `T` is the same type as `U`).

Within the class definition it is possible to leave out the `<T>` from `Vector<T>`, but in my experience mere human beings seem to have more trouble convincing themselves that the function declaration and function definition correspond to each other.  So I generally prefer not doing that .... your call though.

The `<>` syntax is used when explicitly specialising templates, but that's not what you are trying to do.   For example, with a templated function;

```
 template <class T> void foo(T) { /* whatever */   }
 template<> void foo<int> {/* something specific to int */ }
```

Comment: your solution causes linker error, you need to use a different class (instead of T) for friend declaration

Comment: actually this syntax with `<>` is correct, the only thing that confused me was that Stroustrup has not added declaration of operator* before the Vector class. Maybe He wanted to make the book shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Using `<>` is what C++ FAQ [suggests](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends), too.

But you can solve it by simply using the templated declaration like you would normally, except the parameters must be named differently from the class parameters. Then in the separate definition you can again use any type names:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Vector {
 public:
  T i{};
  // Typename must be different from the class typename(s).
  template <typename T_1>
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vector<T_1>& v);
};

// Typename can be any.
template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Vector<T>& v) {
  return os << v.i;
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fPsqcWedf)

That's all. No need for weird `<>` in-between function declaration, or pre-declarations.