# Question about Templates being used in a complex number manipulation function (student from computing 3), error: undefined symbol:

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class MyComplex {
public:

    void setReal(T myreal);
    void setImg(T myimg);
    MyComplex();
    MyComplex(T myreal);
    MyComplex(T myreal, T myi);
    //  template<class U>
    MyComplex<T> operator + (MyComplex<T> const& obj) {
        MyComplex result;
        result.realNum = realNum + obj.realNum;
        result.iNum = iNum + obj.iNum;
        return result;
    }
    MyComplex<T> operator - (MyComplex<T> const& obj) {
        MyComplex result;
        result.realNum = realNum - obj.realNum;
        result.iNum = iNum - obj.iNum;
        return result;
    }
    MyComplex<T> operator * (MyComplex<T> const& obj) {
        MyComplex result;
        result.realNum = realNum * obj.realNum;
        result.iNum = iNum * obj.iNum;
        return result;
    }

    MyComplex<T> operator / (MyComplex<T> const& obj) {
        MyComplex result;
        result.realNum = ((realNum * obj.realNum) + (iNum * obj.iNum)) / (pow(obj.realNum, 2) + pow(obj.iNum, 2));
        result.iNum = ((iNum * obj.realNum) - (obj.iNum * realNum)) / (pow(obj.realNum, 2) + pow(obj.iNum, 2));
        return result;

    }

    void print() {
        if (iNum < 0) {
            cout << realNum << " - i" << abs(iNum) << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << realNum << " + i" << iNum << endl;
        }
    }
    void getInput() {
        cout << "Enter the real number: " << endl;
        cin >> realNum;
        cout << "Enter the imaginary number: " << endl;
        cin >> iNum;
    }
    //    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const MyComplex<T>& U);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const MyComplex& U);
    //    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, MyComplex<T>& U);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, MyComplex& U);

private:
    T realNum;
    T iNum;


};

template <class T>
istream& operator >> (istream& in, MyComplex<T>& U)
{
    cout << "Enter the Real number ";
    in >> U.realNum;
    cout << "Enter the Imaginary number ";
    in >> U.iNum;
    return in;
}
//default constructor
template <class T>
MyComplex<T>::MyComplex()
{
    realNum = 0.0;
    iNum = 0.0;
}
//single argument constructor
template <class T>
MyComplex<T>::MyComplex(T myreal)
{
    realNum = myreal;

}
//double argument constructor
template <class T>
MyComplex<T>::MyComplex(T myreal, T myi)
{
    realNum = myreal;
    iNum = myi;
}
template <class T>
void MyComplex<T>::setReal(T myreal) {
    realNum = myreal;
}
template <class T>
void MyComplex<T>::setImg(T myimg) {
    iNum = myimg;
}

int main() {

    MyComplex<double> num1;
    MyComplex<double> num2, num3, num4, num5;

    cin >> num1;
    cin >> num2;

    num1.print();
    num2.print();

    num5 = (num1 / num2);
    num5.print();

    return(0);
}
```

I am trying to do this code within a template format. However I keep getting this error code.

```
error: undefined symbol: _ZrsRNSt3__213basic_istreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEER9MyComplexIdE (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code) 
warning: Link with `-sLLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED` to get more information on undefined symbols 
warning: To disable errors for undefined symbols use `-sERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0` warning: __ZrsRNSt3__213basic_istreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEER9MyComplexIdE may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library 
Error: Aborting compilation due to previous errors
```

I sent it to my professor and he said the following but I don't quite understand what he means, I don't really want to ask him again. Could someone help me with this? What does he mean

> You need to refer to the class name as MyComplex.
>
> I took out the two friend functions for  i/o.
>
> The operator >> should NOT prompt on cout.  I should not assume input
> is coming from cin.
>
> Perhaps (initially) writing the two operators as non-friend and using
> the accessor/mutator methods would help.  Making them friends is an
> optimization.  Get the code working first.

He sent me a "fixed" code but it still does not work,

Comment: Is all the code in 1 .cpp file like in in the question ?  If not see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Also see this warning about non-template friend function - live - https://godbolt.org/z/fdqPx53jM

Comment: [Why do I get linker errors when I use template friends?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends)

Comment: I think the dup is not correct or at least not yet confirmed by OP.  The non-template friend function is probably the issue,

Comment: This might be a better dupe: [Correct syntax for friend template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692050/correct-syntax-for-friend-template-function)